# Linq to XML: can't find exact root in .xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This question must be easy, but I faced a problem, which I can't deal with:

I download xml file with weather information this way, feel free to check it by using link below:

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile("http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/72503.xml", directoryName);
var xml_file = XDocument.Load(directoryName);
```

And I need to get some numbers from `.xml` file:

```
string str_tweet = "Weather in New York: ";

foreach (XElement el in xml_file.Root.Elements())
        {
            if (el.Name == "fact")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DID U FIND?");
                str_tweet += "temperature " + (string)el.Element("temperature");
                str_tweet += ", humidity " + (string)el.Element("humidity");
                str_tweet += ", pressure " + (string)el.Element("pressure") +"torr";
                str_tweet += ", wind power " + (string)el.Element("wind_speed") +".";

            }
        }
```

So the problem is that `str_tweet` remains the same, and `MessageBox` isn't shown. So actually he didn't find any `fact` root. What am I doing wrong?

Simplified `.xml` file looks this way:

```
<forecast ...> 

<fact>

<observation_time>2014-07-06T03:51:00</observation_time>
<uptime>2014-07-06T04:36:15</uptime>
<temperature plate="fff28e" color="F7F3D3">18</temperature>
<wind_direction>calm</wind_direction>
.......

<fact>
......
</forecast>
```

Comment: does your forecast element has a namepace ?

Comment: @Selman22, honestly didn't understand your question, what *forecast element* do you mean? Anyway, I guess no.

Comment: I'm asking do you have anthing like xmlns="something" in your forecast element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your forecast element has a namespace, then all it's childrens have that namespace too.In that case `XElement.Name` property will return *namespace + element* name, so it won't match with the `fact` . You can change your condition to:

```
if (el.Name.LocalName == "fact")
```

Or, you can specify the namespace and get your elements directly:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://weather.yandex.ru/forecast"; 

foreach (XElement el in xml_file.Root.Elements(ns + "fact"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("DID U FIND?");
    str_tweet += "temperature " + (string)el.Element(ns + "temperature");
    str_tweet += ", humidity " + (string)el.Element(ns + "humidity");
    str_tweet += ", pressure " + (string)el.Element(ns + "pressure") +"torr";
    str_tweet += ", wind power " + (string)el.Element(ns + "wind_speed") +".";
}
```

For more information about Xml Namespaces that a look at: [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx)

Comment: Also, `el.Element(ns + "temperature");`

Comment: And `var ns = xml_file.GetDefaultNamespace();`

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are right but isn't this more appropriate, he might have custom namespace in the future.

Comment: This code won't work, `ns` is just a string. Be careful with `var`.

Comment: `var` must be changed to `XNamespace`